# How to make a simple Spectrum in java

Tags: java, audio-player

I am using [JLayer](http://www.javazoom.net/javalayer/javalayer.html) and [mp3Spi](http://www.javazoom.net/mp3spi/mp3spi.html) to play,stop,pause an .mp3 track.I can take tags from .mp3 like Frames,bitrate,etc and i am trying to make a spectrum of the .mp3

I don't wan't a specific algorith.**I want to know what exactly i need to make a very simple spectrum or something simple retieving a data that changes every (milli or second from the .mp3**).

What libaries or how i can retrieve those data(samples or what?) that make the spectrum change every millisecond or second?

Answer (score 0):

A spectrum can be calculated with a discrete Fourier transformation (DFT). It is typically done in the DSP domain.

I'm not aware of any Java libs for this. Good luck.